# Откуда при вызове экземпляра класса берется None?

Tags: python, функции, классы

Подскажите, откуда в данном примере на выводе получается значение -- None. И как от него избавится?

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, n='John', s='Doe'):
        self.name = n
        self.surname = s

    def identity(self):
        if self.name == 'John':
            print('Some suspicious man!')
        else:
            print(f'My regards {self.name} {self.surname}')

p = Person('V', 'N')
p2 = Person()
    
print(p.identity())
print(p2.identity())
```

Вывод

```
My regards V N
None
Some suspicious man!
None
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Этот вопрос тут кажется далеко не первый раз задают.

```
print(p.identity())
```

В этой строке вы печатаете результат, который возвращает функция `identity`. А что возвращает эта функция?

```
def identity(self):
    if self.name == 'John':
        print('Some suspicious man!')
    else:
        print(f'My regards {self.name} {self.surname}')
```

А она ничего не возвращает, что эквивалентно возврату `None` в питоне. Вот это `None` и печатается.

Сначала вы видите то, что напечатала сама эта функция внутри себя. А потом идёт печать того, что вернула функция.

Поскольку функция ничего не возвращает, её нужно просто вызвать, а возвращаемый результат - игнорировать.

```
p.identity()
```

Либо, если вы хотите не только печатать результат работы функции, но и как-то его, возможно, анализировать (в других местах кода), то можно в функции не печатать результат, а возвращать, и вот тогда имеет смысл печатать результат работы функции:

```
def identity(self):
    if self.name == 'John':
        return 'Some suspicious man!'
    else:
        return f'My regards {self.name} {self.surname}'

print(p.identity())
```

Comment: благодарю. Великолепное объяснение.